# C# reading, editing , writing a file.

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a text file that the user upload to the application through OpenFileDialog then when the file open the program is reading it line by line using:

```
string[] data = File.ReadAllLines(file);
```

how do i make a dynamic editing for each line so that after the Nth number or letter put a space then display the result to the user without writing over the file,

for example:

if my file contain:

```
0000000000BADBAD
2323040007BADAAD
4234420087BADBAC
```

the Display should be

```
0000000000  BADBAD
2323040007  BADAAD
4234420087  BADBAC
```

Comment: Please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have read all the lines into string array, `data is isolated from your file i.e. any modification in data won't be reflected into your file`. You can manipulate it like any other object.

One of the way manipulating data and achieving your result would be:

```
foreach (string value in data)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value.Insert(10, " "));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop throught your lines and extract the data with Regex, example:

```
string str = "0000000000BADBAD";

var match = Regex.Match(str, @"(?<Number>\d+)(?<Text>.*)");

var number = match.Groups["Number"].Value;
var text = match.Groups["Text"].Value;

string result = String.Format("{0} {1}", number, text);
```

And write `result` on your output.

Another alternative is using Linq

```
string str = "0000000000BADBAD";
int n;

string number = String.Join("", str.TakeWhile(c => int.TryParse(c.ToString(), out n)));
string text = String.Join("", str.SkipWhile(c => int.TryParse(c.ToString(), out n)));

string result = String.Format("{0} {1}", number, text);
```